# Cannot set model name dynamically using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to fetch data using model name which should set dynamically using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
$scope.saveResturantDetails=function(billdata){
        console.log('catagory',$scope.answers['catagory0'].value);
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.days.length;i++){
            var cat="'"+"catagory'"+i+"'";
            //var cat='catagory0';
            var subcat="'"+"subcatagory"+i+"'";
            console.log('cat id',cat);
            var data={'cata':$scope.answers[cat].value,'subcat':$scope.answers[subcat].value,'comment':$scope.answers["'comment"+i+"'"]};
            arr.push(data);
        }
        console.log('arr',arr);
}
```

but here I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

but when I am setting the model name like this `var cat='catagory0';` it's coming properly.

The table is given below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in days">
<td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
<td> <select class="form-control" name="catagory[$index]"  id="{{'catagory'+$index}}" ng-model="answers['catagory'+$index]" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCatagory track by cat.value " ng-change="removeBorder('catagory',$index,answers['catagory'+$index].value);" >
 </select></td>
 <td>
 <select class="form-control" name="subcatagory[$index]"  id="{{'subcatagory'+$index}}" ng-model="answers['subcatagory'+$index]" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCatagory[$index] track by sub.value " ng-change="setSubCatagory($index,subcatagory[$index].value);" >
<option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
</select>

</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment[$index]" id="{{'comment'+$index}}" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="answers['comment'+$index]" ng-keyup="comment($index,comment[$index]);"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you make a plukr for this or add controller code for $scope.days and $scope.answers?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variables wrong:

```
scope.saveResturantDetails=function(billdata){
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.days.length;i++){
           console.log($scope.days[i].subcatagory); // should print something
           console.log($scope.days[i].catagory); // should print something
                var data={'cata':$scope.answers[$scope.days[i].catagory].value,'subcat':$scope.answers.[$scope.days[i].subcatagory].value,'comment':$scope.answers["'comment"+i+"'"]};
                arr.push(data);
            }
            console.log('arr',arr);
    }
```

Comment: its is printing `undefined`.

Comment: Does your '$scope.days[i]' object has a property named subcatagory or catagory? if not, your code does not make sense.

Comment: Please check my post again.i need only `d.day_name` to run into a loop other field are input/dropdown field.